# How to add a Property Source to a Spring Cloud Stream Binder's Environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have written a PropertySource that enables `classpath:` prefix for `spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.location` (which out-of-the-box is not supported).
Essentially, this lets me place a truststore.jks inside my Spring Boot application's `src/main/resources` folder and reference it from inside the .jar file.

This works nicely for plain Spring Kafka configurations, like these:

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      ssl.truststore.location: classpath:myTruststore.jks
```

It currently fails when the same configurations are given in the context of a Spring Cloud Stream Binder:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      binders:
        my-binder:
         type: kafka
         environment:
           spring:
             kafka:
               properties:
                 ssl.truststore.location: classpath:myTruststore.jks
```

My PropertySource is not even called back, when I would have expected it to be called with a poperty name of `spring.cloud.stream.binders.my-binder.environment.spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.location`.

I think my PropertySource that would do the `classpath:` resolution is not part of the `Environment` of the given Spring Cloud Stream binder.

**Question:** how can one add PropertySources to a specific Binder's environment (or to all of them)?

Thanks!

**EDIT** 
I add my `PropertySource` in a Spring Boot auto-configuration like this:

```java
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "com.acme.kafka.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@EnableConfigurationPropertiesAcmeKafkaConfigurations.class)
public class AcmeKafkaAutoConfiguration {

  @Bean
  ClasspathResourceSupportEnablingPropertySource acmeKafkaClasspathResourceEnablingPropertySource(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) throws IOException {
    ClasspathResourcesSupport classpathResourcesSupport = new ClasspathResourcesSupport(Files.createTempDirectory(ACME_KAFKA_PREFIX));
    ClasspathResourceSupportEnablingPropertySource propertySource 
        = new ClasspathResourceSupportEnablingPropertySource(ClasspathResourceSupportEnablingPropertySource.NAME, environment, classpathResourcesSupport);
    environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(propertySource);
    return propertySource;
  }
}
```

**EDIT NO.2:** I tried out what Gary Russel suggested below (using a Bean Post Processor declared as a static bean method).

It works but in my case I get a lot of additional warning logs at startup of the form:

`Bean '...' of type [...] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)`

According to [this post](https://synyx.de/blog/bean-x-of-type-y-is-not-eligible-for-getting-processed-by-all-beanpostprocessors/) this can cause some really nasty side effects.

Here is the code I was using (which caused the warnings above):

```java
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "com.acme.kafka.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AcmeKafkaConfigurations.class)
public class AcmeKafkaAutoConfiguration {
  private static final String ACME_KAFKA_PREFIX = "acme.kafka.";

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public static List<ConnectivityConfigurationsProvider> acmeKafkaTokenProviders(OAuth2TokenClient oAuthClient, AcmeKafkaConfigurations configuration) {
    List<ConnectivityConfigurationsProvider> connectivityConfigurationsProviders = new ArrayList<>();
    configuration.getInstances().forEach(serviceInstanceConfiguration -> {
      TokenProvider tokenProvider = new DefaultOAuth2TokenProvider(oAuthClient, serviceInstanceConfiguration);
      ConnectivityConfigurationsProvider connectivityConfigurationsProvider = new ConnectivityConfigurationsProvider(serviceInstanceConfiguration, tokenProvider);
      connectivityConfigurationsProviders.add(connectivityConfigurationsProvider);
    });
    return connectivityConfigurationsProviders;
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  public static OAuth2TokenClient acmeKafkaOAuth2TokenClient() {
    return new DefaultOAuth2TokenClient(new DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient());
  }

  @Bean
  public static ConnectivityConfigurationsProviders acmeKafkaConnectivityConfigurationsProviders(AcmeKafkaConfigurations configuration, List<ConnectivityConfigurationsProvider> connectivityConfigurationsProviders) {
    return new ConnectivityConfigurationsProviders(connectivityConfigurationsProviders);
  }

  @Bean
  static NoOpBeanPostProcessor springKafkaConfigurationsPropertySource(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, ConnectivityConfigurationsProviders connectivityConfigurationsProviders) {
    SpringKafkaConfigurationsPropertySource propertySource = new SpringKafkaConfigurationsPropertySource(SpringKafkaConfigurationsPropertySource.NAME, connectivityConfigurationsProviders);
    environment.getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
    return new NoOpBeanPostProcessor();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnClass(name = "org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderConfiguration")
  static NoOpBeanPostProcessor springCloudStreamKafkaConfigurationsPropertySource(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, ConnectivityConfigurationsProviders connectivityConfigurationsProviders) {
    SpringCloudStreamKafkaConfigurationsPropertySource propertySource = new SpringCloudStreamKafkaConfigurationsPropertySource(SpringCloudStreamKafkaConfigurationsPropertySource.NAME, connectivityConfigurationsProviders);
    environment.getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
    return new NoOpBeanPostProcessor();
  }

  @Bean
  static NoOpBeanPostProcessor acmeKafkaConnectivityConfigurationsPropertySource(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, ConnectivityConfigurationsProviders connectivityConfigurationsProviders) {
    AcmeKafkaConnectivityConfigurationsPropertySource propertySource = new AcmeKafkaConnectivityConfigurationsPropertySource(AcmeKafkaConnectivityConfigurationsPropertySource.NAME, connectivityConfigurationsProviders);
    environment.getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
    return new NoOpBeanPostProcessor();
  }

  @Bean
  static NoOpBeanPostProcessor acmeKafkaClasspathResourceEnablingPropertySource(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) throws IOException {
    ClasspathResourcesSupport classpathResourcesSupport = new ClasspathResourcesSupport(Files.createTempDirectory(ACME_KAFKA_PREFIX));
    ClasspathResourceSupportEnablingPropertySource propertySource 
        = new ClasspathResourceSupportEnablingPropertySource(ClasspathResourceSupportEnablingPropertySource.NAME, environment, classpathResourcesSupport);
    environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(propertySource);
    return new NoOpBeanPostProcessor();
  }

  /**
   * This BeanPostProcessor does not really post-process any beans.
   * It is a way of getting the bean methods that add the property sources
   * above to be called early enough in the lifecycle of Spring ApplicationContext
   * creation. 
   * 
   * BeanPostProcessors are instantiated by Spring extremely early.
   * @Bean methods providing them should be declared as static methods.
   * See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874244/bean-annotation-on-a-static-method 
   */
  static class NoOpBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, Ordered {
    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
      return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

This seems to work:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So61826877Application {

    private static final String KEY = "spring.cloud.stream.binders.my-binder.environment."
            + "spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.location";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61826877Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public static BeanPostProcessor configureSource(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
        Properties source = new Properties();
        System.out.println(env.getProperty(KEY));
        source.setProperty(KEY, "/path/to/myTruststore.jks");
        env.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("cp", source));
        return new MyBpp();
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer<String> input() {
        return System.out::println;
    }

}

class MyBpp implements BeanPostProcessor, Ordered {

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

}
```

```
classpath:myTruststore.jks
...
ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 100
    ...
    ssl.truststore.location = /path/to/myTruststore.jks
    ...
```

Comment: I get a different result to you; inconsistent; but different.

Comment: Thank you Gary! I think my mistake may be in the way that I expose / add the PropertySource to the environment. I updated my question with the code.
I am adding the PropertySource via an Auto-Configuration which might be too late. I read that PSs should be added before a context refresh. How can I expose a PropertySource via auto-configuration properly?

Comment: Interesting; I found a simple solution - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: The BPP `@Bean` factory method should be declared `static`.

Comment: Thanks Gary. That is an interesting solution as well! I finally gave up and added my PropertySource in an `EnvironmentPostProcessor`. This now seems to work. The API docs of `ConfigurableEnvironment` state that "...it is important that [...] PropertySource manipulations be performed before the context's refresh() [...]. This ensures that all property sources are available during the container bootstrap process, including use by property placeholder configurers." 
I assumed that something in Spring Cloud Stream uses said configurers. Static beans may solve it, since they are processed earlier.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I tried your approach, and it works per se. However in my case it results in a lot of warnings stating that beans are ineligible for auto-proxying. I assume it has to do with the fact that my BPP methods have dependencies injected that cause other beans to be created too early in the app lifecycle. This can cause side effects I am concerned about. I updated my post above with the code. Any ideas / thoughts? Thanks